# Add Scrollbar to the legend of telerik RadChart

Tags: wpf, charts, telerik

My client wants a lot of data series to be viewed at the same time so we have a large legend list and it makes the chart area disappear from the chart control.

Is there any way to add a scroll bar to the legend of telerik chart ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the Telerik's documentation with source code -> [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchart-howto-customize-chart-legend-add-scrollviewer.html).

Regards,
Evgenia